# Expandable Listview:Click text header to display images in child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new to android.I find a tutorial(http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/custom-expandable-listview-image-text.html) that wasn't useful at all.

I need to do a `expandable listview:Click text header to display one image in child`.I couldn't find any blogs or tutorials related to this.I find that one but finally it wasn't useful to me.I need a demo related to that.Thank you.

Comment: u send me mail at jeetendra.gupta21@gmail.com, i wil send u complete source code

Comment: @Jeetendra Thank you for your reply.I send a message to your mail id.

Comment: @Jeetendra I seen that.while click the `country` header it displays `child` india,usa,australia,...What I am asking means In `child` image have to display not textView

Comment: not an issue, i wil do it